# setTimeout inside an iframe, problem when focus losses

Tags: javascript, iframe, settimeout

I have an iframe with a simple setTimeout stuff:

```
function load()
{
    setTimeout("reloadContent()", 8000);
}

function reloadContent()
{
    $('#somecontent').doSomething();
    load();
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    reloadContent();
});
```

The problem comes when I lost focus on the parent window (i.e. moving to another program or another tab). It seems like it stack somehow the number of times that it have to reload the content, and then when I regain focus, it executes it all without between delay.

This code fails when I use *jQuery 1.6.2*, but it works with *jQuery 1.3.2*. What am I missing? Is there something important to know about window/parent/iframe(s) blur/focus gain/losses? Any hints or tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to monitor the onblur and onfocus event on your page..

```
    window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        timeoutVarName = setTimeout(...,8000);
    });

    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutVarName);
    });
```

you can do the same thing by using:

```
window.onblur = function(){
    ...
};

window.onfocus = function(){
    ...
};
```

but that wont work in google chrome :)

Comment: I already tried using .blur and .focus methods, but that doesn't make any changes at all. Misteriously, jQuery version change solved it; a bug maybe?

Comment: don't know about jquery, but if you would have used the snippet i pasted it would have worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Smartupdater 3 from http://www.eslinstructor.net/smartupdater3/ and maybe use a div and not an iframe.

You have to use then jQuery